# Why can I not borrow a boxed vector content as mutable?

Tags: vector, rust

Why this doesn't compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut b = Box::new(Vec::new());
    b.push(Vec::new());
    b.get_mut(0).unwrap().push(1);
}
```

While this does:

```
fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(Vec::new());
    let mut b = *a;
    b.push(Vec::new());
    b.get_mut(0).unwrap().push(1);
}
```

And also this does:

```
fn main() {
    let mut b = Vec::new();
    b.push(Vec::new());
    b.get_mut(0).unwrap().push(Vec::new());
    b.get_mut(0).unwrap().get_mut(0).unwrap().push(1)
}
```

The first and third one for me are the conceptually the same - `Box` of a `Vec`tor of `Vec`tors of integers and a `Vec`tor of `Vec`tor of `Vec`tors of integers, but the last one results in each vector being mutable, whereas the first one makes the inner vector immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In at least Rust 1.25.0, all three original examples work. This was a bug in some previous version of Rust.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbox your value before accessing it as a mutable:

```
fn main() {
    let mut b = Box::new(Vec::new());
    b.push(Vec::new());
    (*b).get_mut(0).unwrap().push(1);
}
```

This is because the  `.` operator uses the `Deref` trait instead of `DerefMut`.

The best way to achieve this would be:

```
fn main() {
    let mut b = Box::new(Vec::new());
    b.push(Vec::new());
    b[0].push(1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my English, but I've overdosed caffeine and it is hard to concentrate.

Comment: If the `.` operator only uses `Deref`, then why would `b.push(Vec::new())` work? That requires a mutable receiver, no?

Comment: I have no idea and it is too late for me to think. But `get_mut` will propably get deprecated in favour of `IndexMut`. Instead you can use `b[0].push(1)` and it will work fine. I could investigate it for you tomorrow.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  It's like the compiler is failing to infer that it needs to use `deref_mut` *twice* to reach `get_mut`.  The error is the same if you try to do `b.deref().deref_mut()`.