# Why can I not borrow a variable as mutable more than once at a time with a &mut Box<T> while &mut T works?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a linked list in Rust and I'm having some trouble understanding the difference between these two functions:

```
enum List<T> {
    Nil,
    Cons(T, Box<List<T>>)
}

fn foo<T>(list: &mut Box<List<T>>) {
    match **list {
        List::Nil => return,
        List::Cons(ref mut head, ref mut tail) => {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

fn bar<T>(list: &mut List<T>) {
    match *list {
        List::Nil => return,
        List::Cons(ref mut head, ref mut tail) => {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

`foo` fails to compile, with the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `list` (via `list.1`) as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:66:34
   |
66 |         List::Cons(ref mut head, ref mut rest) => {
   |                    ------------  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here (via `list.1`)
   |                    |
   |                    first mutable borrow occurs here (via `list.0`)
...
69 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

However, `bar` compiles and runs perfectly. Why does `bar` work, but not `foo`? I am using Rust version 1.25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be simplified to

```
fn foo(v: &mut Box<(i32, i32)>) {
    match **v {
        (ref mut head, ref mut tail) => {}
    }
}
```

or

```
fn foo(v: &mut Box<(i32, i32)>) {
    let (ref mut head, ref mut tail) = **v;
}
```

The problem is that `Box` is a a strange, in-between type.

Way back in Rust's history, `Box` was special-cased by the compiler; it knew a lot of the details of `Box`, but this meant that it was "magic" and no one else could implement something that worked like `Box`.

[RFC 130](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0130-box-not-special.md) proposed changing that; making `Box` "just another type". Unfortunately, this still hasn't been fully transitioned.

The details are nuanced, but basically the current borrow checker handles pattern-matching *syntactically*, not *semantically*. It needs to do this to prevent some unsoundness issues.

In the future, non-lexical lifetimes (NLL) just magically fix this; you don't have to to anything (hooray!).

Until then, you can explicitly get back to a `&mut T` with this ugly blob:

```
match *&mut **list {
```

Or call `DerefMut` explicitly:

```
match *std::ops::DerefMut::deref_mut(list) {
```

However, there's [very little reason to accept a `&mut Box<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423).

See also:

- [Destructuring boxes into multiple mutable references seems broken #30104](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/30104)
- [Bad / misleading error message with auto deref and mutable borrows of multiple fields #32930](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32930)
- [Why can I not borrow a boxed vector content as mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28386120/155423)
- [Confused by move semantics of struct fields inside a Box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38243040/155423)
- [Moving out of boxed tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34256165/155423)

Comment: Thanks! So if I understood correctly, the problem is that the `*` operator always uses `Deref::deref()`, even if the `Box` was obtained from a mutable reference? I noticed that explicitly calling `*list.deref_mut()` works too.

Comment: @AndrewSun I clarified some poor wording on my part. `*` can call either `deref` or `deref_mut` depending on the context, but in this case it can't tell that it needs to be `deref_mut`.